# AWS Lambda : Environment variables with "=" via VSTS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, azure-devops

I searched for this but nothing came up.

I have some environment variables with the equals sign in them (ex : "dc=dir,dc=local") but when i deploy my lambda using VSTS everything after the equals sign disapear.

Variable in VSTS
[image: Variable in VSTS]

Variable in AWS Lambda
[image: Variable in AWS Lambda]

I tried using "\" but it doesn't work.

Any ideas ?

Regards

Comment: Does this work if you configure the envvars in the Lambda console?

Comment: What's the detail setting of AWS Lambda Deploy Function? (Environment Variables input box) BTW, the variables should one per line instead of combine them together.

Comment: If i configure them manually in Lambda console it's working.

Comment: It is one variable, it's for a connection to a LDAP Server.

I tried to contact Microsoft, after some tries he advised to open an issue on the git for AWS Toolkit for VSTS.

Comment: What's the detail setting of AWS Lambda Deploy Function task?

Comment: There's a lot of settings there, which one you want to know?

Comment: Environment Variables input box of AWS Lambda Deploy Function task.

Comment: Here's exemple of 2 variables i have :
LAMBDA_VERSION=$(LAMBDA_VERSION)
LAMBDA_ENVIRONMENT=$(LAMBDA_ENVIRONMENT)

Comment: Can you queue the build with "system.debug" variable set to true and then share the logs for AWS Lambda task?

Comment: The AWS task is on the release not on the build. I'm new to this all AWS stuff but I don't think I can set the system.debug to true for the release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment, I assume you specified `MY_VAR=$(MY_VAR)` in Environment variables of **AWS Lambda Deploy Function** task and the `MY_VAR` value is `dc=dir,dc=local`.

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-vsts-tools/blob/master/Tasks/LambdaDeployFunction/helpers/DeployFunctionTaskOperations.ts), you can’t do it, because the environment variable value will be split by `=` and just use first element as the key of AWS lambda variable, the second as the value of variable.

So the environment value `MY_VAR=dc=dir,dc=local` will be split to `MY_VAR`, `dc`, `dir`,`dc`, `local` and the AWS Variable result will be `MY_VAR` as key and `dc` as value.

```
if (taskParameters.environment) {
            request.Environment = {};
            request.Environment.Variables = {};
            taskParameters.environment.forEach((ev) => {
                const parts = ev.split('=');
                request.Environment.Variables[`${parts[0].trim()}`] = parts[1].trim();
            });
        }
```

You need to define them in multiple line (**one per line**) in Environment Variables input box of AWS Lambda Deploy Function task.

Comment: I suspected it was something like that. Do you think it's possible to "escape" the = with something like \=?

Comment: @AnthonyDa No, you can't. I recommended you split them to multiple variables.